# How to add reference to C#?

Tags: c#, voip

I need to add the following reference to my C# project, `MyPhoneCRMIntegration.dll` the directory of this file is `C:\ProgramData\3CXPhone for Windows\PhoneApp`, how can I manage to get this in to my C# project? The instructions on the site I've got from are:

1. Create a new project.
2. Select the .NET language of your choice
   (C#, VB .NET, etc.) and create a new “Windows Class Library” project.
   Ensure that the project targets .NET Framework 4.0.
3. Add a
   reference to the library “MyPhoneCRMIntegration.dll” installed with
   3CXPhone for Windows (usually C:\ProgramData\3CXPhone for
   Windows\PhoneApp).
4. Rename the default class “Class1” to something
   valid for your plugin, for example “MyCrmPlugin”, and then add the
   attribute [MyPhonePlugins.CRMPluginLoader] to the class.

Comment: have you tried the instructions ?

Comment: The instructions look pretty straight forward, what's not working?

Comment: I can't find the dll in the "add reference" menu

Comment: Right click on **References**

Comment: Change from "Framework" to "Browse" after clicking "Add Reference"

Comment: Have you built the class library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

In Solution Explorer, select the project.

On the Project menu, click Add Reference.

The Add Reference dialog box opens.

Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.

In the top pane, select the component you want to reference, and then click the Select button. Press CTRL while clicking to select multiple components.

NoteNote:
**If the component you are looking for is not in the list, you may locate it using the Browse button.**

Click OK when you have selected all the components you need.
Selected references will appear under the References node of the project.