# Merging Two Projects and accessing files from each other in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, projects

I have merged another project in my existing project by right-clicking on the project name and selecting Add->Existing project option. Now i wan't to access the files from my newly added project from the existing one in Visual Studio (Its a C# project) , how can i do this?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045230/how-to-add-reference-to-c

Answer (score 3):

If I'm following your question, you had a solution with a project `A`. You then added an existing project `B`.
You now want to access a file from `A` in `B`. If that's the case, right click on the `B -> References` and add a reference to project `A`. Now you can use the files from that project.

---

Edit: From your comment, I'm not sure if you want to have a separate project / file. If you want them to be only 1, you shouldn't really add a new project, you should add to your project `A` the files you need from project `B`. If you want to keep it as a different module that is included, then the above holds, but you need to realize that usually you have one solution, with many projects inside of it.

Comment: Noctis but now i'm facing another problem, that when i build the project it deploys both the solutions. Why it is so? I have merged the second solution in first and need only first one to work then why it is deploying them as separate projects?

Comment: Because they are separate projects. each projects gets build into it's folder. Usually , if one uses another, one will be a `dll` that will be copied into the other's output directory. Not knowing more of what you're doing, it's hard to say.

Comment: Actually i have developed a windows phone application and one of its module is developed by my friend and he have provided me that module as a separate project so i merge both and now i want to access the pages through each other.

Answer (score 1):

I struggle with this until I found this the link is below:

If you want all windows application to run as one program rather then calling multiple .exe. Then change 'Out Put Type' of each project to 'Class Library'.

Step 1:

You can do that by right-clicking on each Project in solution -> Go to Properties -> Application -> Out Put Type... set it to Class Library

Once you have done that output of these will be generated as .DLL.

Step2:

Add a new Window Form application project, add reference of exiting projects in it so that they can be executed from here.. you can do that by.. right click on main project-> Add Reference->Projects select all existing projects from here.

Now on the main application, you can create 3 buttons to launch each project...

[Inventory]

[Accounts]

[Payroll]

Now in each button code will be something like that...

```
Inventory_click()   
{ 
   Inventory.MainForm frm=new    Inventory.MainForm();  
   frm.show();
}
```

Credit goes to [forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c1ccccc7-13e0-415c-9ccc-492bdfc9983d/c-application-multiple-projects-in-one-solution?forum=csharpgeneral)