# how combine two project in c# (from 1ts project open 2nd project and from 2nd project open 1st project)

Tags: c#

I want to connect two project in c#,i open the 1st project and add 2nd project to it,i added 2nd project to 1st project reference.when the project debug i can open 2nd project form the 1st project form.but i can't write code to open 1st project from 2nd project form.i can't add 1st project to 2nd project reference file.i want to combine 2 project that from the 1st project form open the 2nd project file and again from the 2nd project form open the 1st project form.how do this

Comment: I think this is likely dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580314/merging-two-projects-and-accessing-files-from-each-other-in-visual-studio. However probably what your need is broader than the dupe was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Circular Dependency. If you google it, you'll find many articles and resources about it, one of [them](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616344/What-is-Circular-dependency-and-how-do-we-resolve).

To sum up what they are offering, one thing you can do is to use `Interfaces`, and program against interface, but not concrete class.

Another option is to have third project with core functionality, and just make other two projects reference not each other, but the core project.

One more thing to consider, is do you really need two project, if one should reference another. You talk about forms, so I assume that these projects are related to user interface. In general, there is no need to have two layers for user interface code (of course there are exceptions) if you are going for layered architecture. So if these projects depends on each other a lot, I would keep them in one project.

Comment: thank you for advice Mr mantas cekanauskas..